# Red Hat 7.1 'udev' rules changes – "SYMLINK+" and "NAME"

Tags: linux, rhel, udev

I am trying to install [Oracle ASM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Storage_Management) on Red Hat Linux (RHEL) 7.1, and for that I am trying to configure [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) rules. I have noticed there is a new attribute in udev rules, `SYMLINK+`, which seems to be a replacement for the `NAME` attribute.

Working rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="powerae",  SYMLINK+="ORAdisk1", OWNER="grid", GROUP="oinstall", MODE="0660"
```

Not working rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="powerae",  NAME="ORAdisk1", OWNER="grid", GROUP="oinstall", MODE="0660"
```

I have searched in the Red Hat release note, but I could not find any details regarding udev rules. Are RHEL 6 udev rules compatible with RHEL 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now NAME can not even be changed for network interfaces. 
It is well explained in the older man page below.

[`man udev`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/udev.html)

> `NAME`
>
> The name to use for a network interface. 
> The name of a device node can not be changed by udev,
> only additional symlinks can be created.

Even with [an older release 175](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man7/udev.7.html):

> **`NAME`**
>
> What a network interface should be named.
>
> Also, as a temporary workaround, this is what a device node should
> be named; usually the kernel provides the defined node name or
> creates and removes the node before udev even receives any event. 
> Changing the node name from the kernel's default creates
> inconsistencies and is not supported. 
> If the kernel and `NAME` specify different names, an error is logged. 
> udev is only expected
> to handle device node permissions and to create additional
> symlinks, not to change kernel-provided device node names. 
> Instead of renaming a device node, `SYMLINK` should be used. 
> However, symlink
> names must never conflict with device node names, as that would
> result in unpredictable behavior.

Comment: I submitted a suggested edit, but now I am not sure what you meant. Can you review that? And also can you elaborate your answer (e.g., addressing the question more directly and make more direct statements - e.g. it could begin with *"No, because"*). You can [edit your answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/288877/edit) (but ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).